# Multiple message submission agents - same helo name?

Tags: smtp, exim

Is it okay if we set the same HELO name on multiple MSA servers? Or should they be unique and include the actual server's hostname?

For a small number of reasons, we can't simply have our applications use a single MSA.

Answer (score 1):

You can use whatever you want as identifier, there are however some things to consider.

It is up to the server you connect to to decide how he handles your identifier. The identifier is expected to be the connecting hostname, if it doesn't match there are some things that can happen:

- nothing, the server doesn't care and just accepts your mail
- it decides to increase your spam rating
- it decides to reject your email

What it will do is up to the configuration of the receiving server. If you only use this internally, you can configure your mailserver to accept those mails. If you send these mails directly to external mail servers my advise would be to either use the correct hostname, or, if that is not possible, use a relay server that accepts all your mails and sends them via a valid identifier.